# How can I remove linebreaks with a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, newline

when I run:

```
perl -e '$x="abc\nxyz\n123"; $x =~ s/\n.*/... multiline.../; printf("str %s\n", $x);'
```

I expect result to be:

```
str abc... multiline...
```

instead I get

```
str abc... multiline...
123
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$x =~ s/\n.*/... multiline.../s
```

`/s` modifier tells Perl to treat the matched string as single-line, which causes `.` to match newlines.  Ordinarily it doesn't, resulting in your observed behavior.

Comment: AFAIK, perl doesn't use PCRE. PCRE is a library to mimic perl regex syntax.

Comment: My intended meaning was PCRE, not as a specific library, but as the general set of Perl-compatible regular expression engines, including Perl's.  Perhaps my usage is inappropriate.

Comment: Then how are we supposed to tag questions that relate to the PCRE library?  Anyway, not all "Perl-compatible" regex flavors use /s (or /m, /i, etc.). Languages without regex literals, like Python, Java and .NET, use compilation flags like "DOTALL" or "SingleLine" instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 's' modifier on your regex, so that the dot '.' will match any subsequent newlines.  So this:

```
$x =~ s/\n.*/... multiline.../;
```

Becomes this:

```
$x =~ s/\n.*/... multiline.../s;
```